# The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. when deleting first item

Tags: laravel-7

I'm a beginner in Laravel 7. I am trying to create a checkout form when purchasing items. The problem is whenever I try to delete the first item the 'The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.' shows up. However, I am able to delete the following items under it that I put into the checkout form.

This is my CheckoutController

```
 public function destroy($id)
    {
        Temp_order::where('id',$id)->delete();
            return redirect('checkout')->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
    }
```

And this is the code for the table

```
<tbody>
@forelse ($order as $item)
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="item_code">{{ $item->item_code }}</td>
                                    <td class="cart_product_img" id="image">
                                        <img src="" alt="Unavailable" style="width: 70px; height:70px"></img>
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="item_name">
                                        {{ $item->item_name }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="price">
                                    ₱ {{ number_format($item->price, 2) }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="qty" id="qty">
                                        <div class="qty-btn d-flex">
                                            <div class="quantity">
                                                <input type="number" class="qty-text" id="qty" step="1" min="1" max="300" name="quantity" value="{{ $item->quantity }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="subtotal">
                                    ₱ {{ number_format($item->subtotal, 2) }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <form action="{{ route('checkout.destroy', $item->id) }}" method="post">
                                    
                                        @csrf 
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Remove</button>
                                    </form>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @empty
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <p> NO ITEMS IN CART </p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                            @endforelse
                            </tbody>
```

And this is my route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('ordering', 'OrderingController')->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('inventory', 'InventoryController')->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('checkout', 'CheckoutController')->middleware('auth');
```

Can you help me masters?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update CheckoutController

```
public function destroy(Temp_order $item)
{
        $item->delete();
  
        return redirect('checkout')->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
}
```

Comment: I tried the code you said, but it still wont allow me to delete the first one.